# Linking external JS in UIWebView in iOS 5

Tags: javascript, html, ios5, uiwebview

I am loading an html that includes an external JS like this,

<script src="external.js" / >

This used to work fine, till iOS4.3, but suddenly stopped working in iOS5.0. Based on my understanding it is because UIWebview in iOS 5 now supports html5 which specifies that you "must" put a closing tag instead of relying on '/' (self-closing?) that we are used to put at the end when there is no content in tag.

Let me know if my understanding is correct?

Comment: I don't know, but this explanation just helped me figure out the issue in my app. Thanks!!